# Notice: Undefined index: username

Tags: php

I've got a problem in my log in system, I'm getting these errors:

```
Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\Checkin\index.php on line 13
Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\Checkin\index.php on line 14
```

The lines are like this:

```
    $db = new DB($db['host'], $db['gebruiker'], $db['wachtwoord'], $db['db']);
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["username"]);
    $password = md5(md5($hotel["secret_salt"]) . md5($_POST["password"]));
    $find_sql = "SELECT look FROM users WHERE username = '{$username}' AND password = '{$password}'";
    $run_login = $db->query($find_sql);
```

So, what can i do, i hope someone knows a fix with like isset(); or empty();

Thanks

Wesley

Comment: MD5 is not secure.  Use bcrypt.

Comment: So... have you *tried* `isset`? Because that'd do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right. You need to make use of the **`isset`** construct. Do like this

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"]))
    {
    $db = new DB($db['host'], $db['gebruiker'], $db['wachtwoord'], $db['db']);
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["username"]);
    $password = md5(md5($hotel["secret_salt"]) . md5($_POST["password"]));
    $find_sql = "SELECT look FROM users WHERE username = '{$username}' AND password = '{$password}'";
    $run_login = $db->query($find_sql);
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Username or Password was not passed";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
       $db = new DB($db['host'], $db['gebruiker'], $db['wachtwoord'], $db['db']);
       $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["username"]);
       $password = md5(md5($hotel["secret_salt"]) . md5($_POST["password"]));
       $find_sql = "SELECT look FROM users WHERE username = '{$username}' AND password = '{$password}'";
       $run_login = $db->query($find_sql);

}
```